# Browser caching or page caching... Something is creating issue on page when browser starts

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2, browser-cache

Developing e-commerce site in Codeignter (PHP)
The issue is I have set Show my tabs last opened when FireFox starts. (and it is possible that user would have also set that. See Screenshot.)
[image]

For example.
user registered with the site and login with his credentials.
And, he adds products in cart too.
So, right now he can see that > he is logged in + his items in cart.
Now he closes the browser.
Mean while, admin disable/delete that account.
Now again that user starts the browser he is seeing the same things appeared in the header of the site, Until he refreshes the page.

My meta attributes are like these

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe you should check the database and refresh the sopping cart every time ?

Comment: besides, i think 'admin delete user account' doesn't happen frequently. So under this situation, let user see an error page or something is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox caches the page. You can't do anything with that - its Firefox user settings.

What you can do is force HTTP headers that require page not to be cached at all. Be warned though, you have to apply that to specific pages only, otherwise all of your pages will be requested over and over again.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).